# Replace header and footer with custom header and footer

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7 by default adds HTML DocType, Scripts, Meta Tags and few other things. I want to add my own custom PHP script which has header and footer. How would I do this? It seems that theirs no documentations regarding this.

**Currently I have this few PHP Files on my Theme**

- html.tpl.php
- node.tpl.php
- page.tpl.php
- template.info
- template.php

According to [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327711/drupal-separating-template-code-header-and-footer-with-include) all the doctypes and header information will go in this file **html.tpl.php** on my theme. Well that's what I did. What am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the Drupal cache.